# Threading Tests in Ranorex

Tags: ranorex

I'm not sure if anyone here has experience with Ranorex, but I've got a very large suite of tests. They are testing web services with fairly long processes and the full set of tests takes a little over 7 hours. The tests could be run concurrently (none are dependent upon each other), but I'm not sure if there is any way to set it to run multiple tests at a time. Has anyone had any experience doing this in Ranorex?

Comment: I had a similar issue with Silk and the answer seems to be: scale with hardware, not software

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually you can manage Ranorex tests in a way they run simultaneously. Actually you will need a Ranorex runtime license for that. You can move part of  compiled tests to different computer and run it. Disadvantage is, that you will need to collect test report from multiple sources.

Multithreading would not be possible as Ranorex is using your GUI, is moving your mouse etc. and needs working windows environment, therefore will not work (for example) in multiple accounts on the pc. Once desktop get locked by another user, test will stop.

Potentially you can try to run terminal services on Windows server. Not sure how this will behave as the license is for a single station. Each windows server has 2 simultaneously logged users as terminal services (Remote desktop). With special terminal service licenses you can get theoretically unlimited number of simultaneously working users. If you succeed this way, please let us know.

Another way is to use Ranorex runtime license and multiple virtualised PC's. I get virtualised WinXp working with Ranorex remotely triggered by SSH script from linux build server. I can imagine, there would be more than one virtualised PC. Those can run on your computer trough VMWare player or Virtualbox. Eh, did I tell you that Ranorex license is locked to PC network name? Whatever is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ranorex is a tool for GUI testing, and you need pay license fee for each test machine.
You can try TE.exe from WDK, mainly features:
**1. executes tests in parallel:**

  *te.exe test1.dll /parallel*
**2. executes tests on remote machine:**

  *te.exe test1.dll /runon:MACHINE_HAS_TE_INSTALLED*